# make Doesn't recognise a command

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a makefile to properly automate compilation of my current project.

```
$(kernel): $(assembly_object_files) $(linker_script)
    @echo $(PWD)
    @echo $(PATH)
    @x86_64-elf-ld -n -o $(kernel) -T $(linker_script) $(assembly_object_files)
```

This is the code which is failing. The only error information when making with this is

```
make: x86_64-elf-ld: No such file or directory
```

I have checked that the `x86_64-elf-ld` command exists in the path, and I can indeed execute it with these exact arguments outside of the make file. I have already made sure all of the other variables etc exist, it is the command which is missing. How can `make` be made to include this in its path as well?

EDIT:

The output of the edited code (with `echo`s) is thus:

```
/Repository of Things/Coding/Full Code/Etc/Neutron-OS
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cross/bin:/opt/local/bin:~/opt/cross/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/sbin
make: x86_64-elf-ld: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/kernel-x86_64.bin] Error 1
```

The working directory is as expected and the PATH is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It will be definitely problem with PATH variable, try printing PATH outside on command prompt where its working and also inside GNU make, it will be different.

One option, you need to design some mechanism to update PATH inside make before executing this command.

Or use absolute path of the command [**executable file**].

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this, and the ```path``` within ```make``` contains ```~/opt/cross/bin```, which is where the command is stored.

Comment: ~/opt/cross/bin, is a relative path, are you sure make can access this from your execution point ?

Comment: Well I can access it from the same working directory I run the makefile from, and the working directory never changes during the ```make```.

Comment: In your makefile, print working directory just before this execution. It should be same as your working on, but just for confirmation as I feel make might be working in some other.